# Call activity that extends AppCompatActivity inside tab: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have my Activity that displays 3 tabs. I want to call an activity (extends AppCompatActivity) that contains textviews, buttons, editboxes for displaying data from SQLite. When I click the second tab, the activity is displayed but it occupies the whole screen and is not being displayed inside the second tab.

I am using a pager class for my tabs.

This is the fragment tab that should display my activity inside it:

```
public class settings_tab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings_tab, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I call the activity, it is displayed but it occupies the whole screen and is not being displayed inside the second tab

Activities-in-tabs has been deprecated as a technique **for six years**.

Please use something else for your tabs, such as fragments.

Comment: My issue with using fragments is that some of my codes have an error when I transfer the code of the activity into a fragment class. For example: final Context context = this; <- this line will have an error. and also this one: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);... I do not know what is the substitute for this codes when using fragment.

Comment: @GlennC: "some of my codes have an error when I transfer the code of the activity into a fragment class" -- then ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing your code and explaining what "have an error" means. `Fragment` is not an `Activity`, and so some code changes are to be expected. With respect to `final Context context = this`, most likely that line is not necessary, and even if it is, use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Comment: Then this is what I need, to resolve the issues with the code when I transfer them to a fragment class since activities in tabs are now deprecated. I am just new to android and still exploring the layout design. Thanks for the information. By "have an error" I mean it has a read underline in Android Studio.